# CURLOPT_VERBOSE not working

Tags: php, windows, curl, response

```
Windows 7 x64
PHP 7.2.2 x64
```

I am trying to view a simple request payload so I have created a PHP file per https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch11_07.htm

```
<?php
$c = curl_init('https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'monkey=uncle&rhino=aunt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

but I get absolutely no output unlike the example which shows that I can expect something like:

```
* Connected to www.example.com (10.1.1.1)
> POST /submit.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

monkey=uncle&rhino=aunt* Connection #0 left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

`$page` contains a Google 404 page so I know the request is succeeding.

Does anyone know if there are other settings which I need to address or if I am doing something blatantly wrong? In particular, I am interested in the body of the payload.

Yes, I am aware that curl'ing Google isn't particularly useful; I am trying to get this simple example to work so that I can debug an API interaction which is mysteriously failing.

**Updates, per comment request**

I cannot do `curl -v` but `print_r( curl_version() );` produces:

```
Array
(
    [version_number] => 473344
    [age] => 4
    [features] => 2428829
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.57.0
    [host] => x86_64-pc-win32
    [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.1.0g
    [libz_version] => 1.2.11
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => ftps
            [4] => gopher
            [5] => http
            [6] => https
            [7] => imap
            [8] => imaps
            [9] => ldap
            [10] => pop3
            [11] => pop3s
            [12] => rtsp
            [13] => scp
            [14] => sftp
            [15] => smb
            [16] => smbs
            [17] => smtp
            [18] => smtps
            [19] => telnet
            [20] => tftp
        )

)
```

Comment: Works ok for me, what happens if you `curl -v ...` from the command line?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I've updated my question with your request.

Comment: `-v` isn't version, it's verbose, for the command line tool. I was just wondering if you could get verbose output (and thus, an actual good request) from the same machine via the shell.

Comment: This says output goes to stderr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl  - so have a look wherever your PHP is sending stderr, such as the web server's error log if you're calling this via a web server. Or set a specific file location to capture it with `CURLOPT_STDERR`

Comment: @AlexHowansky I believe Windows PHP uses `php_curl.dll` from the `ext` folder. Are you suggesting that this implies there is a `curl.exe` somewhere on my system? From the `cmd` I get `'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I will take a look at my logs and see if the output is being sent there. I will report back shortly.

Comment: Oops my bad, didn't notice the Windows tag.

Comment: @AlexHowansky No worries. I assume it would work if I used a dedicated executable/binary but I'm trying to figure out why PHP won't "just work" as expected. I tagged `Windows` in the question's tags :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So, PHP was not writing the verbose info to any of my log files: PHP nor Apache and I even checked the event viewer for the heck of it. Adding `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('/curl.txt', 'w+'));` does successfully write to the `/curl.txt` file, fun... I have one more issue now though. The payload body, `monkey=uncle&rhino=aunt`, is not recorded in the log, I just get `* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact` at the end and that is it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm afraid I have no idea why the POST body isn't there. I've never worked with the verbose output in php.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh ok, well thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr**

`CURLOPT_STDERR` **must** be set to something specific.

Setting `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('/curl.txt', 'w+'));` fixed my issue.

---

As it turns out `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` is not printing the output to STDERR for some reason which I have not uncovered. I did not find the output in any of my PHP, Apache, nor Event Viewer logs.

After setting `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('/curl.txt', 'w+'));`, I was able to see the output in the `curl.txt` file.

I am not sure if this is specific to Windows environments.

Comment: If `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` set `TRUE`, `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` will not work.